# How can I change a value in a json-like-string with a loop in python 3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, loops

Here is my string:

```
{"query":"{\"format\":\"article-timeline\",\"from\":**0**,\"isLiveWirePage\":true,\"section\":\"/markets\",\"sections\":\"/markets\",\"size\":6,\"sort\":\"display_date:desc\",\"types\":\"\"}","d":"176","_website":"coindesk"}
```

Comment: What are you searching for, can you format the code and add a bit of explanation that you are doing, where you are facing issues, and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
counter = 0

for i in range(10): # from 0 to 9
    querystring = '{"query":"{"format":"article-timeline","from":'
    querystring += str(counter)
    querystring += ',"isLiveWirePage":true,"section":"/markets","sections":"/markets","size":6,"sort":"display_date:desc","types":""}","d":"176","_website":"coindesk"}'
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a nested dictionary.

```
querystring = {'query': {'format': 'article-timeline', 'from': 0, 'isLiveWirePage': True, 'section': '/markets', 'sections': '/markets', 'size': 6, 'sort': 'display_date', 'types': ''}, 'd': '176', '_website': 'coindesk'} 



querystring['query']['from'] = 6666666
```

ResultSet:
[image: Click to see image]

Comment: querystring is in your solution not a string. It is a dictonary. If you would like to manipulate querystring as a dictonary, you have to do some extra steps, because querystring is actual a string. Also true != True.

Comment: @robni I thought It was a dictionary. After correcting missing parts I wanted to show how to assign a value. Of course, I agree with the rest of what you wrote.

Comment: If you do the correct conversion from a string (querystring) to a dictionary you will deserved an upvote. And I will give you my upvote. I'm sorry, but until you do, this isn't an answer to that question.